# Reflection and multi dimensional arrays

Tags: java, reflection

I have code that uses reflection on an input object and does some processing on the data stored in the object. The input object can be anything like String or int or double etc., sometimes it can be a multi dimensional array. I know how to do it for two dimensional arrays but I would prefer something that would work for any given dimensional array. Any guidance to get this accomplished will be helpful. Thanks,

Comment: Ever since I started messing with C and pointers, I found multiple-dimension arrays the wrong answer to any programming question.  The one exception might be math-based matrix manipulation, but anything with that much math should probably be treated as data an not code anyway (written in a math-language).  Otherwise nested structures, nested arrays or nested pointer/array combinations always seem to read more clearly. It could certainly be that I just haven't seen the right problem though..

Answer (score 6):

Sounds like you need either recursion or a loop, or both.

```
void getStuffFromArray(Object obj) {
    // assuming we already know obj.getClass().isArray() == true
    Class<?> componentType = obj.getClass().getComponentType();
    int size = Array.getLength(obj);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        Object value = Array.get(obj, i);
        if (value.getClass().isArray()) {
            getStuffFromArray(value);
        } else {
            // not an array; process it
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: nice answer. I worked up some similar code, but you got it first.

Comment: why do you need to pass in "clazz" separately? isn't it just obj.getClass()?